# Home made biriyani masala paste

Tags: rice, indian-cuisine

What is the permitted preservative for biriyani paste? How much quantity of what should I add? My masala has ginger, garlic paste, onions, tomatoes, green chillies, spice powders, mint and coriander leaves, lemon juice, salt, gingely (sesame) oil, and ghee. I need it to have a shelf life of one week outside the refrigerator!

Am preparing this curry paste and packing in plastic airtight containers and freezing. After freezing I courier to whoever needs it. Hence for transportation purposes, I need a shelf life of one week.

[image]

Comment: 'permitted' might be something that's different by country.  Also, are you going to be water canning this, or pressure canning, or some other preservation technique?  Will this be stored in a cold cellar or closer to 'room temperature' (which also varies by country)

Comment: I edited in what you said in an answer about transporting the paste and a few other little things. If I changed anything from what you meant to say, you can always edit it back. Welcome to Seasoned Advice!